# change a field value only once in a period of time using laravel php-mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table with some attributes including `timestamp` , this table contains fields about invoices when user enter `invoice` values as incorrect form in the first time i want to change value inside invoice only once in period of time `24 hours` after he added item !! i want to prevent him to make any changes when invoice exceeded `24 hours` , i use laravel framework

Comment: If you want to prevent an action, usually you put code in your controller to prevent such an action.

Comment: But you can build it into the query itself.

Comment: ok ! when i show all items for editing i want to build condition for check if items was added before 24 hours if true he can editing it , else he can't

Answer (score 0):

On your Invoices Model you need to add a protected $timestamp set to true;

Then when a record is created or updated the field created_at / updated at will be automatically filled.

So there is a included feature to handle datetimes in laravel is a library called [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

and as tadman and Khalid suggested in your controller you can do :

```
<?php
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use Carbon\Carbon;
 use Invoice;

class FooInvoiceController extends Controller
{
/**
 *
 * Method to check if invoice is editable
 *
 * @param $invoiceId
 * @return bool
 */
public function isInvoiceEditable($invoiceId)
{

    $now = Carbon::now();

    $invoiceCreatedAt = Invoice::where('id', $invoiceId)->get()->created_at;

    $diffInHours = Carbon::parse($invoiceCreatedAt);

    $length = $diffInHours->diffInHours($now);

    if ($length > 24) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
/**
 * @param $invoiceId
 */
 public function fooAction($invoiceId)
 {
    if ($this->isInvoiceEditable($invoiceId)) {
        // Work here
    }
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways you can go about enforcing this business rule:

1. If all updates in your application occur through Http than you can handle it in your controller(s)

```php
class InvoiceController extends Controller
{
    // ...
    public function update($id, Request $request)
    {
        $invoice = Invoice::findOrFail($id);

        abort_if($invoice->created_at < Carbon::now()->subHours(24), 
            422, "Updating is no longer available.");

        // proceed as ussual (validate, save, fire events, etc)
    }
    // ...
}
```

2. You can also make the model itself enforcing this rule by listening for `updating` event and returning `false` if updating period expired, which will prevent saving the changes for the model.

```php
class Invoice extends Model
{
    // ...
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        self::updating(function ($model) {
            return $model->created_at !== null &&
                $model->created_at >= Carbon::now()->subHours(24);
        });
    }
    // ...
}
```

3. If you have to be selective about what attributes can or can't be updated you can implement individual mutators for each protected attribute and throw an Exception if updating period expired.
4. Depending on database you're using you can potentially handle on database level with triggers.